# Apple turns all my Applications Dark at Night

Tags: macos, dark-mode

Apple is turning all my applications to Dark after 8PM. Below is Notepad editor plus its doing it for Internet Chrome. Nightshift is also turned off.

Anyone know how to fix this back to regular white?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System Preferences > General

Switch to Light instead of Auto

[image]

Comment: do you have answer for this question maybe? https://superuser.com/questions/1670600/apple-mac-book-pro-launchpad-order-items-alphabetically

Comment: Sorry, no. I took one look at Launchpad when it was introduced & vowed never to use such an abysmal user interface. Never looked at it since. It defies the laws of physics - it sucks & blows at the same time. Leave it on phones, it doesn't belong on computers.

Comment: so what do you use then?

Comment: I actually still use DragThing [which no longer works after Mojave] - I posted a question on Software Recs a while back, which describes it & asks about replacements. - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/58667/dock-style-app-to-replace-dragthing