# Apple Mac Book Pro, Launchpad Order Items Alphabetically

Tags: macos, launchpad

How do I order items in Mac Book Pro Alphabetically in Launchpad? They are currently unorganized and I want to order. Right clicking to order does not have menu to sort .

Following command does not work either,

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

[image]

Currently have MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2018.
Mac OS Big Sur

Prefer to look for automated auto arrange solution, not Manually dragging/dropping

Comment: Some ideas: (1) Drag the Applications folder onto the Dock, ensuring it is set as a Stack and sorted in Name, and use it instead. (2) Use [Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com/home.php) ($7.99 for up to 5 computers, trial available).

Comment: I'd recommend sticking clear of the macOS app launcher. I use [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/), which is a text based launcher like Spotlight just faster. As [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) said, Launchpad Manager could be a solution.

Comment: It appears it used to be possible to program the Launchpad. Take a look at this post on [the Mac Observer](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/alphabetizing-mac-launchpad/). I found [dmdeller / launchpad-editor](https://github.com/dmdeller/launchpad-editor) which is an old solution to editing the order of the Launchpad.

Comment: On a similar note to Launchpad Manager and launchpad-editor, I've been poking around in the macOS launchpad SQLite database. Refer to [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/18553/285729) to figure out where the database is stored on your computer. The item order is stored in there, but not in an immediately interpretable format. I might mess around and see if I can edit the order using sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Launchpad cannot be ordered alphabetically, except manually,
I suggest to use instead the Applications folder which is already
ordered alphabetically:

Drag the Applications folder onto the Dock, ensure that it is set as
a Stack and  sorted in Name, and use it instead.

A useful third-party software product is
[Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com/home.php),
commercial license at $7.99 for up to 5 computers, and a trial is available.
It can do the ordering and much more.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can order them alphabetically... manually.  Just drag them into the order you want.  I've never heard of another way to sort/view in Launchpad, but I also never use it anyway.

If I want to launch Slack (and if it's not in my Dock), I press my Spotlight shortcut key (Cmd-Space), type "Slack", then Return.

Or setup a keyboard-shortcut tool.  I use Apptivate to launch my most-used apps.

Maybe if Apple had a touch-screen the Launchpad would make sense, but until then, there are much better ways to find and launch apps...

Comment: yeah, I Know I can manually drop and drag, looking for automated auto arrange solution obviously, thanks though

Comment: If you find one, and then down about my answer. But I don’t think there is one, unless there is a way to edit the underlying config file that stores the app order.